# How to get validated field name and not arg0 when ConstraintViolationException is thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I am using Spring @Validated Annotation to Validate a Get Request Path Variable. I do get a ConstraintViolationException thrown which I handle in a @ControllerAdvice class, but the problem is that I want the name of the field and I'm getting a arg0 instead of the name itself (myField)

I know there are similar questions to mine but I've tried the following and nothing solved it.

I already tried iterating through the exception

```
        for (Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ConstraintViolation<?> next =  iterator.next();
            System.out.println(((PathImpl)next.getPropertyPath())
                    .getLeafNode().getName() + "  " +next.getMessage());
        }
```

as well as compiling with -parameters (in pom.xml)

```
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
```

And also creating a configuration file for the validator, like this:

```
        @Bean
        public Validator validator(){
            final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                    .configure()
                    .parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider())
                    .buildValidatorFactory();
            return validatorFactory.getValidator();
        }
```

This is the method I am validating

```
public void method(@RequestParam(value = "myField") @Pattern(regexp = "^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$", message = "is not valid") String myField)
```

But after all, I am still getting the arg0 when checking the exception object.
Using Java 8 with Spring Boot 1.5

Comment: I'm having the same issue after upgrading the version of Spring Boot from 2.2.13 to 2.5.6. I'm unable to configure the tests to run while resolving the parameter names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just in case someone faces this problem in the future, I want to share my findings here)

In the end, I noticed I was injecting a @Validator in my Application class
return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

This was messing with the validator used by Spring in my case